# Combining batch actions with manual actions in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, actions

I need some help. In the past few weeks I have found a large portion of archived ww2 documents. Now I'm trying  to make proper PDF's out of these files but there is one issue. The archiver who digitized the documents has left a black space around the documents which I obviously would like to remove. This issue however is that the documents differ in size, position and rotation. I have added an example file.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to design an action which allows me to manually crop a file and then save and close it. in general the batch and action should open the image, allow me to crop and then continue to save and close the file for me. I want to have a minimum of mouse and keystroke actions as we are talking avout several 10.000 images which have to be processed.

Can any one help me?

Cheers[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There are tools for this that are way beter than photosop can be.

Comment: @Scott: I have made an Action which has an Open, Stop, Save and Close action. Then start a batch process on all the files but immediatly after the stop it fails.

Comment: @joojaa: any tip you got is welcome!

Comment: @Joonas: Yes it does for a large part. I do have one more question. It now lets me adapt an allready existing crop. Is it possible to allow me to set my own crop manually?

Comment: I think what you describe is just how the crop tool works in Photoshop CC (maybe CS6). When you pick the crop tool, you already have a pre-existing crop. Or it's sort of a placeholder, that you can ignore and just draw the crop area however you like. Another possibility that comes to mind is that the crop tool basically does the same thing but wraps itself around any selections you might've made before picking the crop tool. A third possibility is that your crop tool has a fixed size set in the tool options, that forces it to be a specific size. Did you try drawing the crop area?

Comment: If you can find a gear icon in the crop tool options, you can enable classic mode from there. It might be a bit easier to use in this case.

Comment: I believe the fact that I recorded a manual crop action is the cause for a preset crop which I manually have to adapt. I might have a solution for that which I need to test later on when I'm at home. Let you know if my thought works.

Comment: So I just tried it and it seems like it's one part of what I was saying before and one part of what you were describing. So first of all, yes... If you record the action using a specific preset or any specific settings, it will try to honor them to the best of its abilities. What you should probably do is, when you start recording cropping, click the little icon that looks like circle with an arrow pointing counter clockwise. It's at the far right of the crop tool's options bar. This will reset the current settings to defaults and that gives you more wiggle room later.

Comment: You can actually resize or redraw the crop area before you apply the action (as long as you don't change the width and height values manually). When you run the action, it will start the cropping in that size and you can resize it to whatever size you want. So like I was saying before, no matter what, when you run the action, it will sort of activate the crop area immediately, but you can resize it by grabbing the corners. What I didn't know is that you can't apparently redraw the crop area by clicking and dragging when it's recorded as a step.

Comment: This is kind of a _drag_, because while it doesn't change the end-result, it makes using the crop tool potentially more cumbersome, because you may have to first drag one corner and then drag the opposite corner to resize/move it where you need it. When you run the action, it might be easiest for you to move (click and drag) the crop area to the center of what you're cropping and then resize it from one corner using the Alt modifier. Also, the classic mode I was talking about before is likely a little easier to handle when moving the crop area around.

Comment: Perhaps think about using Adobe Lightroom instead of Photoshop. It's much easier to make multiple manual edits to thousands of photos/scans. It's what it was designed for.

Comment: Thnx Joonas, My Idea hasnt worked. Yours seems to work just fine enough to I can now manually adapt the crop. hit enter and the batch proces continues to the next image.

Comment: @BillyKerr Im not really that familiar with lightroom. Can it handle diffrent sizes and positions of to be cropable images?

Comment: @Buck_Compton - yes absolutely. It's fast too, there's no saving needed between edits. Cropping is non-destructive. All edits can be output at the end in one go.

Comment: Try [ScanTailor](https://scantailor.org). It's meant for cleaning scans and coincidentally actually works a lot like Lightroom in that you can edit images one by one but you can also apply the edits to all of them. Hope you have windows though, cause it's Win only. Here's the unprocessed and processed files in the "out" folder: [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t8gpxqyn7ja5y3m/AACBLzg-hQ3iVjXxm9YrP8Qua). I also put in a video there. Apparently you're supposed to change the settings, apply to all pages and then press the play button to apply them to all files.

Comment: @billykerr I have lightroom here but my wife uses it for reworking of her photos she isn't familiar with what I would like to have done. Could you explain what I could do best to get the result im looking for?

Comment: @Buck_Compton - I can't give you a full tutorial here. But basically you could import an entire folder full of images, then you could use the crop tool in Develop mode to crop and straighten each image, apply it, and move on to the next image. Assuming all have similar lighting, you could apply exposure, contrast, black level and white level adjustments to just the first image, then sync the same settings to every image. To output select all the images and hit Export.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you I have made two runs of about 500 pictures today. Resized and reworked lighting settings. It works just fine. I guess this was the way to get it done most practically! Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Buck, I guess you missed my comment about ScanTailor or didn't  realize that it can detect the content area automatically, which would potentially mean that you could've processed all images in one click with perhaps some additional tweaks. I had a video in the dropbox link above.

Comment: @Joonas I guess I did miss that one, Very interesting going to look if it works later on today!

Comment: @Joonas I had a look it works fine but it has an issue with landscape oriented files. These are essentially the most important of what I have collected so far. Couldn't find a way to manage that so far.

Comment: Odd. It does have that rotation function, so you'd think it would work with both orientations. What kind of issue?

Comment: @Joonas Have a look at this [example] (http://heritage.canadiana.ca/view/oocihm.lac_reel_t7080/1063?r=1&s=1). These pages actually are the most important files of the archives I have downloaded. What it does is it sometimes detects the entire file. Sometimes just the dates and sometimes just the mainbody text. I was unable to find out how to correct this error.

Comment: Yea, I can see the issue... It's the second action "Split Pages". The default setting expects book scans. Cause you know when you scan a book, you're likely to have part of the other page included... And so since here there's a clear gap between the horizontal content and the number thing, it automatically places a split there. So the first thing you should do when you open the project in this case is: Click action 2 "Split pages", then in there click the first icon (manual) in the "Page layout" section and then click the change button to apply this setting to all pages then click play btn.

Comment: The 4th action "Select Content" is still not perfect, but at least now you're not going to be missing stuff randomly and you'll see the blue crop area that you can adjust manually if it didn't quite find the content or clipped some of it. You should also be able to change each setting in an existing project too and just reapply with the play button.

Comment: [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zIllImwsDKM). Also I noticed that `Page up` and `Page down` let you move between the pages

Comment: @Joonas Thank you it seems to work quite ok right now. I guess I need some more time to learn the software. Thank you for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want remove the black areas but keep the info on the right side you may be able to make an action which automatizes this completely. It works for this image, but it depends on how different the tens of thousands of images are.

1. Convert the *Background* layer to a *Smart Object*.
2. Add a *Filter > Minimum* filter with a *Radius* of *6 px* and *Preserve* set to *Roundness*. This removes the number in the top of the image and unwanted white dots in the black areas.
3. Add a *Threshold* adjustment and leave the *Threshold Level* at the default *128*. Now all pixels darker than 50% black will turn completely black.
4. Apply *Image > Trim* with *Based On* set to *Top Left Pixel Color*. This crops away the black area.
5. Enter *Image > Canvas Size*. Check *Relative*, and add *16 px* to both the width and the height with the *Anchor* set to the center. This way you make sure that you get a tiny black border around the white areas so you don't crop away any of the white area.
6. Turn off the *Threshold* layer and the *Smart Filters*.
7. Flatten the image and save.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answers it works just fine on a test but the matter is that I like the adittional ribbon to be deleted as well. Havn't figured out how to do just that. As resizing the canvas doesnt work because position and size differ a lot per ribbon

Comment: Is the white page always to the left like in this image? And always the same size more or less? Then you could crop once more to the size of the page to get rid of the ribbon.

Comment: No the pages have different sizes. That's the main issue for getting a good action for it.